# mapping between 2 sets of ASCII characters

Tags: c, binary

We only have to use **bitwise** operations to do this. Any hint will be appreciated. Just started learning c.

**input:**
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**output:**
hpxdlt|aiqyemu}bjrzfnv~cks

and this is the code stub we are asked to follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int inChar, outChar;
while ((inChar = getchar()) != EOF)
{
  // Your bitwise code appears here…

  // last instruction in while loop
  putchar(outChar);
}
return 0;
}
```

function getchar() returns an
integer expressing the ASCII encoded character from the standard input.The putchar() function converts the specied integer into the corresponding ASCII character and posts it to the standard output

Comment: Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We'll help you with your solution, but we aren't going to write it for you.  This question does not show sufficient effort on behalf of the asker.

Comment: I don't know where to begin

Comment: Write out the numbers for the first few characters of each set in binary, and look for a pattern.

Comment: Trying to do, however put char doesn't print anything.

Comment: the numeric values of asciil characters:  [ascii-int table](http://www.asciitable.com/)   The referenced table gives all the information that you need to perform this assignment.

Comment: Look at the corresponding pairs of characters in binary. Identify the part of the binary number that stays the same in each pair, and the part that changes. Look at the part that changes, and work out how.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in c#. I believe you can derive the parallel code in c for it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"<input_file>"))
        {
            StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                var charFromFile = sr.Read();
                input.Append((char)charFromFile);

                var isFirstBitset = IsBitSet(charFromFile, 0);
                var isSecondBitset = IsBitSet(charFromFile, 1);
                var isFourthBitset = IsBitSet(charFromFile, 3);
                var isFifthBitset = IsBitSet(charFromFile, 4);

                // If first bit is set
                if (isFirstBitset)
                {
                    charFromFile = SetBit(charFromFile, 3);
                    if (!isFourthBitset)
                        charFromFile = ClearBit(charFromFile, 0);
                }

                // If 2nd bit is set
                if (isSecondBitset)
                {
                    charFromFile = SetBit(charFromFile, 4);
                    if (!isFifthBitset)
                        charFromFile = ClearBit(charFromFile, 1);
                }

                // if 4th bit is set
                if (isFourthBitset)
                {
                    charFromFile = SetBit(charFromFile, 0);
                    if (!isFirstBitset)
                        charFromFile = ClearBit(charFromFile, 3);
                }

                // if 5th bit is set
                if (isFifthBitset)
                {
                    charFromFile = SetBit(charFromFile, 1);
                    if (!isSecondBitset)
                        charFromFile = ClearBit(charFromFile, 4);
                }

                output.Append((char)charFromFile);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Input = {0}", input.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Output = {0}", output.ToString());
        }

    }

    public static bool IsBitSet(int b, int pos)
    {
        return (b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
    }

    public static int SetBit(int value, int bitToSet)
    {
        return value | (int)Math.Pow(2, bitToSet);
    }

    public static int ClearBit(int value, int bitToClear)
    {
        return (value & ~((int)Math.Pow(2, bitToClear)));
    }
```

Comment: the question was to implement in C, not C#

Comment: I know. I wanted to provide solution logic through c#. Guess it wouldn't be a big deal to derive the logic and implement in C.  I guess you can just look for the code to set, clear and check state of bit on internet and use it in place. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

 bool IsBitSet(int b, int pos)
 {​​​​​​
      return (b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
 }​​​​​​

 int SetBit(int value, int bitToSet)
 {​​​​​​
     return value | (int)pow(2, bitToSet);
 }​​​​​​

 int ClearBit(int value, int bitToClear)
 {​​​​​​
     return (value & ~((int)pow(2, bitToClear)));
 }​​​​​​

  int main(void)
  {​​​​​​
     unsigned char inChar= 0, outChar=0;
while ((inChar = getchar()) != EOF)
{​​​​​​
    // Your bitwise code appears here…
    char isFirstBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 0);
    char isSecondBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 1);
    char isFourthBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 3);
    char isFifthBitset = IsBitSet(inChar, 4);

    // If first bit is set
    if (isFirstBitset)
    {​​​​​​
        inChar = SetBit(inChar, 3);
        if (!isFourthBitset)
            inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 0);
    }​​​​​​

    // If 2nd bit is set
    if (isSecondBitset)
    {​​​​​​
        inChar = SetBit(inChar, 4);
        if (!isFifthBitset)
            inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 1);
    }​​​​​​

    // if 4th bit is set
    if (isFourthBitset)
    {​​​​​​
        inChar = SetBit(inChar, 0);
        if (!isFirstBitset)
            inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 3);
    }​​​​​​

    // if 5th bit is set
    if (isFifthBitset)
    {​​​​​​
        inChar = SetBit(inChar, 1);
        if (!isSecondBitset)
            inChar = ClearBit(inChar, 4);
    }​​​​​​

    outChar = inChar;
    putchar(outChar);
}​​​​​​
return 0;
 }​​​​​​
```

Comment: check out the solution in C language.